# Application thread keeps running

Tags: java, websphere

We are using `Websphere Work Manager` (CommonJ) for spawning threads in our application. We are making use of the default `WorkManager` and through `JNDI` accessing it in our application.

```
try {  
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();  
    wm = (WorkManager) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/wm/App_WORKMANAGER");  
    wm.schedule(this);  
    //threadScheduler = new Thread(this);  
    //threadScheduler.start();  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    // catch the exception  
}
```

We keep running the threads which listens to different queues to check for any message and process it. We do get hung messages as below , came to know this can be configured from admin console to stop showing the warning/error or increase the hung detection time.

> [1/30/13 6:50:38:708 EST] 00000032 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 2" (00000022) has been active for 708969 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.

Now if we stop the application from admin console, these thread don't get stopped and we keep getting the Hung messages. For another deployment another set of threads adds up to the Hung thread count.
I read somewhere that if we declare thread as `Daemon` then they get stopped (). So is it fine that we declare the threads as `Daemon` as below or we need to override the `release()` method too? Our `release()` is empty as of now.

```
public boolean isDaemon() {                        
  return true;  
}  

public void release() {  
 //TODO  
}
```

How exactly can we stop the application thread from running once the application is stopped? It's an old application using `Struts 1.x`.

I read two explanation here:

1. [Thread keeps running even after application has been stopped in Websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659609/thread-keeps-running-even-after-application-has-been-stopped-in-websphere) (as I'm not using spring, just declaring `Deamon` is fine? And this will work if we stop the JVM itself, just stopping app from console wont help, correct?)
2. [Does Websphere respect Daemon threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274222/does-websphere-respect-deamon-threads/9274435#9274435) (the approach suggested by Sarel Botha is the only solution or we have some setting from console to get the job done.)

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to create a startup/shutdown listener for the application the stop the threads there

Comment: Thanks Aviram, I'am going to try the same with a servlet context listener. Though it will be bit tedious as the app don't have a common service for creation of theads..  would have to dig down to get to each thread.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in your use case the `isDaemon` method should return `true` and you need to implement the `release` method in such a way that it stops the code executing in the `run` method of the `Work` object. If you do this, then the hanging thread warnings will disappear, and WebSphere will call `release` on all running `Work` objects when the application is stopped.

Comment: Thanks Andreas..  I have written a contex listener and am putting all thread references to null. Still have to check how far it works. Yes, i have declared the threds as Daemon, and looks like it has suppressed the hung thread warnings. In run method we keep looking for the queue, so cant do much on release i guess. So keeping my bet on putting the refrences to null.

Comment: Andreas putting ref as null wont work.. Idea of implementing release() did the trick..  thanks for helping out..